# Is there any way to improve QTP’s debug engine like it was possible in QTP 9.2 with pdm.dll?

Tags: debugging, qtp

in this article described [how to improve QTP’s debug engine](http://www.advancedqtp.com/2008/03/vs2008-pdm-dll-dramatically-improves-qtp%E2%80%99s-debug-engine/) 
Is there anything possible for QTP 10 and QTP 11?

Thank you!

Comment: +1, did not know about all that.

Comment: The link above appears to have moved to: [VS2008 & PDM.DLL dramatically improves QTP’s debug engine](http://www.advancedqtp.com/vs2008-pdm-dll-dramatically-improves-qtp%E2%80%99s-debug-engine/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://depenga.com/QTP-debugger-tweak-with-pdm.dll, the newer pdm.dll works fine with QTP 10. I have yet to verify...